# Babel plugin development for react-intl

Tags: javascript, babeljs, react-intl, babel-core

I noticed that there are some performance gain opportunities for react-intl after comparing `intl.formatMessage({ id: 'section.someid' })` vs `intl.messages['section.someid']`.
See more here: https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/issues/1044

The second is 5x faster (and makes a huge difference in pages with a lot of translated elements) but doesn't seem to be the official way to do it (I guess they might change the variable name in future versions).

So I had the idea to create a babel plugin that does the transformation (formatMessage( to messages[). But I'm having trouble doing it because babel plugins creation is not well documented (I found some tutorials but it doesn't have what I need). I understood the basics but didn't find the visitor function name I need yet.

My boilerplate code is currently:

```js
module.exports = function(babel) {
  var t = babel.types;
  return {
    visitor: {
      CallExpression(path, state) {
        console.log(path);
      },
    }
  };
};
```

So here are my questions:

- Which visitor method do I use to extract classes calls - intl.formatMessage (is it it really CallExpression) ?
- How do I detect a call to formatMessage ?
- How do I detect the number of parameters in the call ? (the replacement is not supposed to happen if there is formatting)
- How I do the replacement ? (intl.formatMessage({ id: 'something' }) to intl.messages['something'] ?
- (optionally) Is there a way to detect if formatMessage really comes from react-intl library ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Which visitor method do I use to extract classes calls - intl.formatMessage (is it it really CallExpression) ?

Yes, it is a `CallExpression`, there is no special AST node for a method call compared to a function call, the only thing that changes is the receiver (callee). Whenever you're wondering what the AST looks like, you can use the fantastic [AST Explorer](https://astexplorer.net/). As a bonus, you can even write the Babel plugin in the AST Explorer by selecting Babel in the Transform menu.

> How do I detect a call to formatMessage ?

For brevity I will only focus on the exact call to `intl.formatMessage(arg)`, for a real plugin you would need to cover other cases as well (e.g. `intl["formatMessage"](arg)`) which have a different AST representation.

The first thing is to identify that the callee is `intl.formatMessage`. As you know, that is a simple object property access, and the corresponding AST node is called `MemberExpression`. The visitor receives the matching AST node, `CallExpression` in this case, as `path.node`. That means we need to verify that `path.node.callee` is a `MemberExpression`. Thankfully, that is quite simple, because `babel.types` provides methods in the form of `isX` where `X` is the AST node type.

```
if (t.isMemberExpression(path.node.callee)) {}
```

Now we know that it's a `MemberExpression`, which has an `object` and a `property` that correspond to `object.property`. So we can check if `object` is the identifier `intl` and `property` the identifier `formatMessage`. For this we use `isIdentifier(node, opts)`, which takes a second argument that allows you to check that it has a property with the given value. All `isX` methods are of that form to provide a shortcut, for details see [Check if a node is a certain type](https://github.com/thejameskyle/babel-handbook/blob/master/translations/en/plugin-handbook.md#check-if-a-node-is-a-certain-type). They also check for the node not being `null` or `undefined`, so the `isMemberExpression` was technically not necessary, but you might want to handle another type differently.

```
if (
  t.isIdentifier(path.node.callee.object, { name: "intl" }) &&
  t.isIdentifier(path.node.callee.property, { name: "formatMessage" })
) {}
```

> How do I detect the number of parameters in the call ? (the replacement is not supposed to happen if there is formatting)

The `CallExpression` has an `arguments` property, which is an array of the AST nodes of the arguments. Again, for brevity, I'll only consider calls with exactly one argument, but in reality you could also transform something like `intl.formatMessage(arg, undefined)`. In this case it's simply checking the length of `path.node.arguments`. We also want the argument to be an object, so we check for an `ObjectExpression`.

```
if (
  path.node.arguments.length === 1 &&
  t.isObjectExpression(path.node.arguments[0])
) {}
```

An `ObjectExpression` has a `properties` property, which is an array of `ObjectProperty` nodes. You could technically check that `id` is the only property, but I will skip that here and instead only look for an `id` property. The `ObjectProperty` has a `key` and `value`, and we can use [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to search for the property with the key being the identifier `id`.

```
const idProp = path.node.arguments[0].properties.find(prop =>
  t.isIdentifier(prop.key, { name: "id" })
);
```

`idProp` will be the corresponding `ObjectProperty` if it exists, otherwise it will be `undefined`. When it is not `undefined` we want to replace the node.

> How I do the replacement ? (intl.formatMessage({ id: 'something' }) to intl.messages['something'] ?

We want to replace the entire `CallExpression` and Babel provides [`path.replaceWith(node)`](https://github.com/thejameskyle/babel-handbook/blob/master/translations/en/plugin-handbook.md#replacing-a-node). The only thing left, is creating the AST node that it should be replaced with. For that we first need to understand how `intl.messages["section.someid"]` is represented in the AST. `intl.messages` is a `MemberExpression` just like `intl.formatMessage` was. `obj["property"]` is a computed property object access, which is also represented as a `MemberExpression` in the AST, but with the `computed` property set to `true`. That means that `intl.messages["section.someid"]` is a `MemberExpression` with a `MemberExpression` as the object.

Remember that these two are semantically equivalent:

```
intl.messages["section.someid"];

const msgs = intl.messages;
msgs["section.someid"];
```

To construct a `MemberExpression` we can use [`t.memberExpression(object, property, computed, optional)`](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-types#memberexpression). For creating `intl.messages` we can reuse the `intl` from `path.node.callee.object` as we want to use the same object, but change the property. For the property we need to create an `Identifier` with the name `messages`.

```
t.memberExpression(path.node.callee.object, t.identifier("messages"))
```

Only the first two arguments are required and for the rest we use the default values (`false` for `computed` and `null` for optional). Now we can use that `MemberExpression` as the object and we need to lookup the computed property (the third argument is set to `true`) that corresponds to the value of the `id` property, which is available on the `idProp` we computed earlier. And finally we replace the `CallExpression` node with the newly created one.

```
if (idProp) {
  path.replaceWith(
    t.memberExpression(
      t.memberExpression(
        path.node.callee.object,
        t.identifier("messages")
      ),
      idProp.value,
      // Is a computed property
      true
    )
  );
}
```

Full code:

```
export default function({ types: t }) {
  return {
    visitor: {
      CallExpression(path) {
        // Make sure it's a method call (obj.method)
        if (t.isMemberExpression(path.node.callee)) {
          // The object should be an identifier with the name intl and the
          // method name should be an identifier with the name formatMessage
          if (
            t.isIdentifier(path.node.callee.object, { name: "intl" }) &&
            t.isIdentifier(path.node.callee.property, { name: "formatMessage" })
          ) {
            // Exactly 1 argument which is an object
            if (
              path.node.arguments.length === 1 &&
              t.isObjectExpression(path.node.arguments[0])
            ) {
              // Find the property id on the object
              const idProp = path.node.arguments[0].properties.find(prop =>
                t.isIdentifier(prop.key, { name: "id" })
              );
              if (idProp) {
                // When all of the above was true, the node can be replaced
                // with an array access. An array access is a member
                // expression with a computed value.
                path.replaceWith(
                  t.memberExpression(
                    t.memberExpression(
                      path.node.callee.object,
                      t.identifier("messages")
                    ),
                    idProp.value,
                    // Is a computed property
                    true
                  )
                );
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };
}
```

The full code and some test cases can be found in [this AST Explorer Gist](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/ef4d7bd3a6473d3070f11b6b59f81789/84fc6eb0a8b1f366f8002db04166e6fb7d90eaaf).

As I've mentioned a few times, this is a naive version and many cases are not covered, which are eligible for the transformation. It isn't difficult to cover more cases, but you have to identify them and pasting them into the AST Explorer will give you all the information you need. For example, if the object is `{ "id": "section.someid" }` instead of `{ id: "section.someid" }` it won't be transformed, but covering this is as simple as also checking for a `StringLiteral` besides an `Identifier`, like this:

```
const idProp = path.node.arguments[0].properties.find(prop =>
  t.isIdentifier(prop.key, { name: "id" }) ||
  t.isStringLiteral(prop.key, { value: "id" })
);
```

I also didn't introduce any abstractions on purpose to avoid additional cognitive load, therefore the conditions look very lengthy.

Helpful resources:

- [Babel Plugin Handbook](https://github.com/thejameskyle/babel-handbook/blob/master/translations/en/plugin-handbook.md)
- [`babel-types`](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-types)
- [AST Explorer](https://astexplorer.net/)
- [Code Transformation and Linting with ASTs - FrontendMasters course by Kent C. Dodds](https://frontendmasters.com/courses/linting-asts/)

Comment: Michael, thank you so much for the very best answer. I'll try it today. :)

Comment: Thanks one more time. Nor you helped to solve my problem, taught me how to do plugins but also probably helped other react-intl users. I've shared your answer here in react-intl github issue https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/issues/1044